# Java applet issue: dll already loaded in another classloader

Tags: java, applet, java-native-interface, classloader

I need to create a Java applet which loads a local DLL. It works fine, but only the first time. If I refresh the page, it always complains by throwing the following exception:

```
Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native Library E:\test.dll already loaded in another classloader
```

Any ideas on how I can fix this?

Here is my code:

```
public class NativeWrapper
{
    public native String GetIP();

    public NativeWrapper(final String nativeLib) {
        try {
            System.load(nativeLib);
        } catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError e) {
            System.out.println("UnsatisfiedLinkError exception" + e);
        }
    }
}
```

And the applet code:

```
public class MyApplet extends Applet {

    private static NativeWrapper dll = new NativeWrapper("e:/test.dll");

    public MyApplet () {
    }

    // to be called by javascript on html page
    public string GetIPAddress() {
        return dll.GetIP();
    }
}
```

I have read a lot on this issue but still can't find a solution. Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This article](http://j-integra.intrinsyc.com/support/kb/Article.aspx?id=122967) seems to provide some good advise to make sure you get the same `ClassLoader` for each applet invocation.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you so much! Issue resolved. I always look at how to fix the issue in the java source code, but the fix is on how to embed the applet in HTML!

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the same issue by adding following snippet to the applet tag on the html page.

```
<param name="classloader_cache" value="false">
```

I have following param in the applet's JNLP file. That might be also relevant.

```
<applet-desc ...>
    <param name="separate_jvm" value="true"/>
</applet-desc>
```